# BreezeJS Cascade Delete with Not Null FK

Tags: breeze

Hello I am having a problem with cascade delete when using breezejs, which by the way I think it rocks. Specifically I use the Asp.net Mvc SPA template with AngularJS and BreezeJS(1.3.1 version). I have a Customer Object that has a Phone object navigation property. Phone has an FK to Customer that is set to NotNull and Cascade Delete.

My problem is when trying to delete the parent Customer on the client and call SaveChanges ( this is a Web Api method) I get an DbUpdateException on SqlServer "The Update statement conflicted with a foreigh key constraint....".

I see that the breezejs client sends back the Customer Object marked as Deleted and the Phone Object marked as Modified although I didn't edit the Phone explicitly.

Apparently when setting the FK on Phone to nullable, I have no exception, the parent Customer object is deleted but the Phone object is not deleted, instead its FK to Customer is set to null.

I want the Phone object to be deleted too but keep the FK column to notnull. I would appreciate any help.

EDIT UPDATE:

### Well the problem is I guess when you call EntityManager.saveChanges() on the client. If you delete the Customer parent object its entityState is set to deleted and all the FK references are set to null as in Phone object which now has EnityState "Modified". But the call to EntityManager.saveChanges() will cause an Update and a Delete in the server which causes the conflict is the FK on the Phone is set to "Not Null". Calling EntityManager.saveChanges([Customer]) might work.

## #

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're assessment is correct and I'll try to add more.

When you call setDeleted() for the customer, breeze nulls all referencing fkey values -- in your case: in the phone record.  The result is the customer in the deleted state and the phone in the modified state.  Calling saveChanges results in an UPDATE to phone and a DELETE for customer.  If phone's customer ref is nullable, this should succeed (assuming that the UPDATE is done before the DELETE).  If it's non-nullable, I would expect a client-side error saying phone's customer ref is null.  But, if the client didn't catch it, then the server would.

You say you want to delete phone along with customer.  You could setup customer to cascade deletes.  Then, saveChanges([Customer]) should work.  Afterwards, you probably should evict (detach) that phone record from the cache since it's actually gone.  If you tried to save it afterward, the server would fail on the UPDATE statement since the record didn't exist.

Or I think you could call setDeleted on the phone record too and then call saveChanges() to save both.  I assume breeze would do two DELETEs.  I assume it would *not* try to update the record as well.

Comment: Actually, I had to do `saveChanges([Phone, Customer])` after deleting all entities to keep the cache updated, like you mentioned